# Modifying/Animating a UISplitView on iPad - Navbar issues

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview, core-animation

I am creating an iPad application using a UISplitView. I used the default template for that type of application in Xcode. The UISplitView has a left pane (menu or list) and a right pane (detail or content view) in it. Each has a navigation bar at the top of the view.

What I want to do is move (with animation) both views to the left so that the list pane is hidden and I can have more controls appear at the right. Please don't tell me I am going against the HIG, I am sure I am, but for what I am doing it makes perfect sense and this is how I want to do it.

The problem is that, after animating the slide across, I am left with little dots at the top and bottom of the screen where the dividing line used to be. The dots are obviously there to curve the corners of the nav bars when they are in the correct place, but now they are just in the way, but I don't know what view they are in or where I can find them. I either want to remove them just before the animation or just disable them completely.

Here is a screenshot of the problem: http://cl.ly/1WEC You can see the dots in the middle of the picture. They also occur at the bottom of the screen.

Here is a video of the animation so far: http://f.dapl.me/1hSY5Y

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a custom interface such as this, you might be better off doing without UISplitViewController and simply managing your own view layout.  Even if it were possible to solve your immediate problem and still use UISplitViewController for now, it would be more likely to break in the future if Apple changes that class.  It shouldn't be too hard to handle this with a custom view controller/view managing a couple of subviews.

Comment: My solution was to put the UISplitViewController's view into another 'root' view in the window and then animate that. However the solution isn't great so I am re-thinking the layout.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Matt Gemmell's custom SplitView Controller.  it does exactly what you want to do.
http://mattgemmell.com/2010/08/03/mgsplitviewcontroller-updated

Here is the source:
https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController

Comment: I did in the end. Thanks anyway though.